# Ionic Shadow-root css

Tags: css, vue.js, ionic-framework

In my Vuejs project have the following ion-select that I am trying to stylize with shadow-root but no matter what I do no styling is never applied to neither ion-select-option, ion-alert nor ion-radio. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the select:

```
  <ion-col size-sm="8">
      <ion-select placeholder="select">
        <ion-select-option value="1">option1</ion-select-option>
        <ion-select-option value="2">option1</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
  </ion-col>
```

And here is the css, I also tried to apply classes:

```
<style scoped>
 ion-select::part(text) {
   color: white;
 }
ion-select-option::part(text) {
--border-radius: 4px;
--inner-border-radius: 4px;

--color: #ddd;
--color-checked: #6815ec;
}
ion-alert::part(text) {
  color: #c00000;
  background-color: #c00000;
}
ion-alert::part(text) {
  color: #c00000;
  background-color: #c00000 !important;
}
ion-radio::part(text) {
  --border-radius: 4px;
  --inner-border-radius: 4px;

  --color: #ddd;
  --color-checked: #6815ec;
}
```

Comment: There are a set of available props to edit the shadow dom: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#css-custom-properties